# How to use jqPagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination, jqpagination

Please help me, I don't know how to use **jqPagination** (http://beneverard.github.com/jqPagination/). I would each page which have other content. Ex, page 1, the content is a paragraph, page 2 is other paragraph. And I don't want click show/hide to show the content.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right,  I can only assume you have code similar to this:

```
<div class="some-container">
    <p>My first paragraph</p>
    <p>My second paragraph</p>
    <p>My third paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#" class="first" data-action="first">&laquo;</a>
    <a href="#" class="previous" data-action="previous">&lsaquo;</a>               
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
    <a href="#" class="next" data-action="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    <a href="#" class="last" data-action="last">&raquo;</a>
</div>
```

And you want to show / hide each of your paragraphs in order using jqPaginaton, try the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // hide all but the first of our paragraphs
    $('.some-container p:not(:first)').hide();

    $('.pagination').jqPagination({
        max_page    : $('.some-container p').length,
        paged        : function(page) {

            // a new 'page' has been requested

            // hide all paragraphs
            $('.some-container p').hide();

            // but show the one we want
            $($('.some-container p')[page - 1]).show();

        }
    });

});​
```

Take a look at this [working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/beneverard/2HLZF/), it demonstrates the use the plugin to be able to show and hide a range of paragraphs. Of course this example could be extended to work with other elements / scenarios too.

Be sure to comment back on whether this solved your problem.

Comment: You're very welcome, any more jqPagination questions post them here on Stack Overflow with the `jqPagination` tag, it'll appear in my RSS reader.

Comment: @BenEverard :  is it possible to get data using ajax and php in jqpagination?

Comment: jqPagination abruptly stopped working, this fiddle doesn't work anymore either.  Was there an update?

Comment: Looks like Github doesn't support serving raw JS files, jsfiddle is using these as references so that'd be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am using jPages. This works fine.

Just give your page an id. And place a div underneed this information.

in you jQuery you just can add this:

```
$(".holder").jPages({
    containerID: "pageDivId",
    perPage: 3
});
```

The holder is the new div you created. And the containerId is the id of your entire pagediv.

You can check jPages [here](http://luis-almeida.github.com/jPages/)